# TS infers unknown return type of my generic function, how do I prevent that? In a generic way?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I know that the title sounds confusing. I don't know how to explain my problem in one sentence. But this code explains what I mean:

```js
// This is the class that I want to extend further on.
class User {
    public name: string

    constructor(name: string) {
        this.name = name
    }
}

type Constructable<InstanceType> = {
    new (...args: any[]): InstanceType
}

type MyFactory<InstanceType> = {
    newWithRandomName(): InstanceType
}

type ExtendedClass<InstanceType, ClassType extends Constructable<InstanceType>> = ClassType & MyFactory<InstanceType>

// This is the function that I use to extend the class.
function extendClass<InstanceType, ClassType extends Constructable<InstanceType>>(
    classType: ClassType
): ExtendedClass<InstanceType, ClassType> {
    return new Proxy(classType, {
        get(target, prop, receiver) {
            if (prop === "newWithRandomName") {
                return () => new classType("Joe Random")
            }

            return Reflect.get(target, prop, receiver)
        }
    }) as ExtendedClass<InstanceType, ClassType>
}

const ExtendedUser = extendClass(User)

// Both of these lines work as expected
let user1 = new User("John Doe")
let user2 = new ExtendedUser("Jane Doe")

// But this line returns an unknown type,
// even though I thought I clearly defined
// what type should be returned, didn't I?
let user3 = ExtendedUser.newWithRandomName()

console.log(user3.name)
```

[And here's a playground that you can play with](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBUAsEsGdTqALpApqAxgGwIa3ijkqAJKgDuOAdsUgPaioAeSqVAJqAGYCuATilR9QdKgDoAUNjzwAqrCGgA3hNBrQABx4AjLNAygqOALaoAXKFhI+0KgHMJq9RlFW+PDPT4AKI6YtutnYAlMpO6uoocGJ+6AC8hiao4aAAvhLpEkgAnhroAMKu1h5IOLqoADwkVFbUGKjguagAfKAJKhFUqOSg3mL9OHx2sBbU2QDaALrBFtW1VPWNeRmOOXmgALLZAGI4nnR82VU1pQsNTa3tKV3kAOrQKABK1Ox0xgBySd4zpCd158tMmt0ABRFhsdiodj5XD4Y7zRZNAA0oBhMiW6GYrA48EKJ3cnjKWEqc1OiLyzUuqNhsAxoAAZJsdnsvEdSf8Mc1HCAIDB4IhBNweAskNBRMhIERSKAeApkAwsRCJehpPhJLwRWKqIxwRw0XD2WcMSj9bSmjrsexcUUCaVyvCyQCWs1vClVWa8hZTRiJD8wZaoaaHRzkdT0RcwhE+KgkPxtTdQAAFPh0JjZbzu42RiLqOwx7ylIYxlEaFMaFHR+rQABuQlCHRzjegXF6pboGjacQSACIbvcni83p9TN36ylG43o7G+Nrvm1WgnM01vN2AFJ0dDPDhvUfjieZCc5qdx0CPVBcYmeMR5pAFwY3ktliuoKu1vjBPdqdIRVKhPCgf0IUDGlgyNUNvQuFYpCKADdUhdh5EUBJFT1GlvEQ99uTAAAhOgUBEFtBDlPQungcgDgAa1Af9mDyTwoQkYliFlIQAEY2kMbpQAwld10gbUABEN13JiZQUPgACYOITQCOChHi12odAhNQXcJB5bCeFoPlQBI9BjxneBqBlKgKKoOhyG1YEkXUsBUFrKzIDoHg7EgaUUGc1ziDIbBUEGLBslASEuFsBieXISVaHNWAnJ4LBOG0fSYzjKEUXYaB2CoABybyAH5GJjMShAAZg42T4IwmJun7SAt1eD4vg-aCajoYkxCwOg7G8Fi+GKmIkmCIA)

Answer (score 0):

You dont need two generic parameters, take a look below:

```js
// This is the class that I want to extend further on.
class User {
  public name: string

  constructor(name: string) {
    this.name = name
  }
}

type MyFactory<T> = {
  newWithRandomName(): T
}

type ExtendedClass<T extends new (...args: any[]) => any> = T & MyFactory<T>

// This is the function that I use to extend the class.
function extendClass<ClassType extends new (...args: any[]) => any>(
  classType: ClassType
): ExtendedClass<ClassType> {
  return new Proxy(classType, {
    get(target, prop, receiver) {
      if (prop === 'newWithRandomName') {
        return () => new classType('Joe Random')
      }

      return Reflect.get(target, prop, receiver)
    }
  }) as ExtendedClass<ClassType>
}

const ExtendedUser = extendClass(User)

// Both of these lines work as expected
const user1: User = new User('John Doe')
const user2: User = new ExtendedUser('Jane Doe')

// But this line returns an unknown type,
// even though I thought I clearly defined
// what type should be returned, didn't I?
const user3: User = ExtendedUser.newWithRandomName()

console.log(user3.name)
```

Comment: Your code only works because you write `const user3: User = ...`. If you removed the `: User`, then TS says that it doesn't think `user3` is of type `User`, but instead TS thinks that `user3` is of type `typeof User`. And so `user3.name` is not `User.name`, but `Function.name`, according to TS. I've been able to get it to work by forcing types, but I was hoping that there was a way to make it work without forcing types.